# How does skype use p2p on iOS?

Tags: ios, p2p, skype

I'm unclear how Skype works on iOS.

Skype does not seem to be using Apple's multipeer connectivity framework. And from what I have read, you cannot establish a direct p2p connection between user A and B if they do not have a publicly routable IP Address. If Skype is a p2p application how does it manage to work on iOS? Is it possible to create a p2p application without using the multipeer connectivity framework?

Comment: You might want to edit this down to focus only on iOS, since that seems to be your main question. I think it's likely to get closed as too broad as it is right now. I tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: In general "How does X do Y?" will be too broad for SO, but it sounds like you're asking something specific here -- how does it transmit data without using Apple's multipeer connectivity framework? -- but I don't know enough about the subject matter to edit it more. I'm also pretty sure that iPhones do have publicly routable IP addresses, just like normal computers, but I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer.

Comment: Thank you very much I need stackoverflow very much but I new here so I dont know how to word my question right and thus my previous questions have been taken down! It will be of great help if someone could explain!

Answer (score 3):

Skype detects if a peer is directly reachable using public IP address or NAT traversal techniques. If the peer is not directly reachable, it uses relaying mechanism using another peer which can directly connect to the unreachable peer. Skype also displays its performing a relaying while doing a file transfer when the  peer is not directly reachable.

Comment: What would cause A to be unreachable by B but reachable by C, aren't all peers equal in a network of peers?

Comment: If C is machine with public Ip address it should be reachable from both peers. Skype has internal algorithm where it makes a particular system as relay server if it has sufficient bandwidth, CPU & public IP.